# How to write smaller text in nodes and how to change node colors

Tags: tikz-arrows

So I have states and nodes drawn in my tikz project. Now I want my node's text look smaller and go INSIDE the middle of node. Also how to change text and node color?

My code for nodes:

```
   \documentclass{article}

     \usepackage{verbatim}
        \usepackage{pgf}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
        \usepackage{iftex}
        \ifPDFTeX
           \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
           \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
           \usepackage{lmodern}
        \else
           \ifXeTeX
             \usepackage{xltxtra}
           \else 
             \usepackage{luatextra}
           \fi
           \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
        \fi
        \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
        \tikzset{
        state/.style={
               rectangle,
               rectangle split,
                rectangle split parts=2,
                 rectangle split part fill={red!30,blue!20},
               rounded corners,
               draw=black, very thick,
               minimum height=4em,
               inner sep=3pt,
               text width=3cm,
               text centered,
               },
    }
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=4cm,
                        semithick]

      \node[state] (A) {};
      \node[state]        (B) [below right of=A]{};
      \node[state]         (C) [right of=B] {};
    ....

         \path       (A) edge                node {}(D)
                     (B) edge                node {OK} (E)
                         edge    [bend right]node {Error} (F)
                     (C) edge               node {OK} (E)
                         edge               node {} (F)
                     (D) edge  [bend right] node {Error} (F)
                         edge              node {OK} (E)
                     (E) edge              node {} (B)
                         edge   [bend left]node {>}(C)
                         edge              node{}(G)
                     (F) edge  [loop above]node{Error}(F)
                         edge              node{OK}(E)
                    (G) edge  [bend right] node{Error}(F);
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you write a Minimal but complete example? From `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. You code is not compilable in this way.

Comment: @Ignasi added more code :)

Comment: Thank you by your effort, but your code is still not compilable. Did you try it? At least `\end{document}` is missing just like nodes D, E, F, G.

Comment: Node's text color changes with option `text=red`, text size is fixed with option `font=\small`, node's fill color with `fill=blue`.

Comment: @Ignasi how to write it correctly into my code?

Comment: @Ignasi I have one more question. maybe you have any suggestions how to write node text in other side of arrow (just for few nodes)?

Comment: Why don't you write some usable code? this way we have some initial point to modify. In any case your questions are all of them already answered here or in first tutorials in `TikZ` documentation. Open a command window a type `texdoc --view pgfmanual`

Comment: @Ignasi Fill isn't changing nodes arrows, text works perfect :)